# jQuery: Animate, Hide and show content

Tags: jquery

When user clicks on Edit, I want to hide the Edit link, then hide the content above and show a hidden div.

I was able to do that however how can I revert that process if the user clicks on Cancel button?

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/r3wen43u/1/)**

```
$('.js-edit').click(function(){

  // Hide 'Edit link'
  $(this).fadeOut(200);

  // Push down 'other' div
  $('.other').animate({
    'marginTop' : "+=400px" //moves down
  });

  // Hide content
  $('.hide-content').delay(200).fadeOut(200);

  // Show hidden content
    $('.show-content').delay(400).fadeIn(200);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can revert what all you made. May be this? Improved with [A. Woff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff)'s method:

```
$(".js-cancel").click(function() {
  if ($('.other,.hide-content, .show-content').is(':animated')) return;
  $('.js-edit').fadeIn();
  $('.other').animate({
    'marginTop': "-=400px" //moves up
  });
  // Show content
  $('.hide-content').delay(200).fadeIn(200);

  // Hide shown content
  $('.show-content').delay(400).fadeOut(200);
});
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dafckouL/1/**

Comment: Clicking multiple times quickly on each button cause weird behaviour. This would fix it:  `if ($('.other, .hide-content, .show-content').is(':animated')) return;`  http://jsfiddle.net/dafckouL/1/

Comment: @A.Wolff Added and updated. Given due credits... `:D`